# Normal distribution with known mean and unknown variance (product of two variables)

Tags: normal-distribution, gamma-distribution, conjugate-prior

Assume there is a data point $x$ sampled from a Normal distribution:
$$\begin{align}
x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\frac{1}{yz}) \propto (yz)^{1/2} \exp [-\frac{1}{2} (x-\mu)^2yz]
\end{align}$$
 where $\mu$ is the known mean, $\frac{1}{yz}$ is the unknown variance, $y$ and $z$ are both unknown.

Further assume $y$ and $z$ are both sampled from Gamma distributions:
$$\begin{align}
y \sim Gamma(\alpha_1,\beta_1) \propto y^{\alpha_1 - 1} \exp[-\beta_1 y]
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
z \sim Gamma(\alpha_2,\beta_2) \propto z^{\alpha_2 - 1} \exp[-\beta_2 z]
\end{align}$$
whrere $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are the shape parameters and $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are the rate parameters.

The posterior distribution $p(y|x,z)$ is
$$\begin{align}
p(y|x,z) &\propto p(x|y,z) p(y) \\
& \propto z^{1/2} y^{\alpha_1 - 1 + 1/2} \exp[-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2 yz - \beta_1 y]\\
& = z^{1/2} y^{\alpha_1 -1 + 1/2} \exp\Big[ [-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2z - \beta_1] y \Big]
\end{align}$$

My question is: by observing the above expression, is it correct to say the posterior distribution $p(y|x,z)$ is a Gamma distribution : $Gamma(\alpha_1 + 1/2, \frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^2z + \beta_1)$? Is it correct to absorb the $z^{1/2}$ term in the above expression into the normalization constant of the Gamma distribution, because $z$ is considered given and fixed in this posterior distribution?

Comment: Yes completely correct.